# Querying Postgres JSONB column by key with dynamic values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have model `UserPost` which has JSONB column `posts` and the data stored in that will be JSON having `user_id` as the key (dynamic) and some attributes as values. Consider that I have multiple `user_posts` records like below,

Record 1:

```
 id: 1
 posts: { 
          1: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' },
          3: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' }
        }
```

Record 2:

```
 id: 2
 posts: { 
   { 
      2: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' },
      5: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' }
    }
```

Record 3:

```
id: 3
 posts: { 
   { 
      1: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' },
      2: { message: 'some', posted_at: 'sometime', attachment_url: 'some_url' }
    }
```

I have `user_ids` say `2, 5` for which `UserPost` records have to be fetched, how will I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found it,

**Single key:**

```
UserPost.where("posts ? '2'")
```

**Array of keys:**

```
UserPost.where('posts ?| array[:keys]', keys: ['1', '2'])
```